# Connect to Remote Server with Power BI

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

Within my company there's the wish to use Power BI.
This should be connected to a server which is on a Remote Desktop.
The users don't have access to this Remote Desktop, so want to use Power BI locally.
Is this possible, because I can't find a way?

Comment: You can check my article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-power-bi/

Answer (score 0):

You can install powerbi in your local machine and connect to remote server to get the data

Comment: Yeah, but how tho?